# How to use stored procedure output in sql query in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to pass output of stored procedure inside where condition in Sql Query

E.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_test 
WHERE id IN (Ids are out from stored procedure.).
```

Comment: i think you need to use table valued function instead of SP

Comment: Why you need to write as sproc?

Answer (score 0):

You want `INSERT INTO ... EXEC` :

```
INSERT INTO @tableVariable(id) -- table variable needs to be created first
EXEC SP_Name <parameter if any>


SELECT tt.*
FROM tbl_test tt INNER JOIN
     @tableVariable tv
     ON tt.id = tv.id;
```